# get pairs that are not explicit

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this example data frame

```
df <- data.frame(v1= factor(sample(x = c("y", "n"), size = 100, replace = T)), 
                 v2= factor(sample(x = c("a", "b", "c"), size = 100, replace = T)))
```

I now want the unique pairs (v1,v2) to see what levels a value in v1 can take in v2.
I this simple case a solution would be

```
unique(expand.grid(df))   #maybe add sort
```

but my data.frame is huge and has over 1000 factor levels, my machine crashes when I do it. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick `dplyr` answer:

```
df %>% group_by(v1) %>%
       distinct(v2)
```

If you want it sorted, add on:

```
%>% arrange(v1,v2)
```

Also, if your real data is as simple as this example (no other columns) you can just call:

```
distinct(df)
```